# fullScreenRequested does not work fully in my test browser that uses PyQt5

Tags: python, video, browser, fullscreen, pyqt5

I am building a browser with python using pyqt5. I enabled fullscreen support and also enabled plugins,

```
self.webView.page().fullScreenRequested.connect(self.handleFullscreenRequest)
QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled, True)
```

As you can also see that I connected fullscreenrRequested signal to a function called self.handleFullscreenRequest . Here is the function,

```
    def handleFullscreenRequest(self, request):

       print("requested")

       if(request.toggleOn()):
          request.accept()
          self.gridLayout.removeWidget(self.webView)
          self.webView.setParent(None, QtCore.Qt.Window)
          self.webView.showFullScreen()
       else:
          request.accept()
          self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.webView)
```

Result:

- It works very well with youtube videos, facebook videos. Videos get full screen when requested.

Problems:

- It doesn't work for videos of some websites including dailymotion. Video 
  plays but never gets full screened.
- I think it doesn't event emits the fullScreenRequested signal, as nothing is printed from handleFullscreenRequest() function in the console.

I want videos from any website to play in fullscreen mode if requested. Help me geeks please.

Comment: What Qt version are you on?

Comment: PyQt5.8.2 .... sorry for replying late.

Comment: Do you have a minimal runnable example and a link to a video which doesn't work? Seems to work fine to me on dailymotion.